# Query Execution time for a sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, performance, sharding, database

I have configured a sharded cluster with MongoDB.
I want to compare the query execution time between a sharded cluster and a single database (no sharding).
For the single database I am using system.profiler to get the execution time of each query.
But for the sharded cluster system.profiler is not avaiable.  I searched on the net but I cannot find how to get the total execution time of a query over a sharded cluster.
Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use mongo's [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) method for this. Example:

For single database:

```
db.users.find({username: "joynalabedin"}).explain().millis
```

This will return query execution time in milliseconds.

For sharded cluster:

```
db.visitors.find({"siteId" : "511ffa78-9a1d-4c33-a3aa-4b4417ca4afc"}).explain('executionStats')
```

In the returned output, there are three properties in executionStats:

- executionTimeMillis - Query execution time
- totalKeysExamined - Total number of index entries scanned
- totalDocsExamined - Total number of documents scanned to find the
  results

Adtional resources:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#sharded-collection